# Showing error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unhighlight is not a function', Even after loading the Highlight.js plugin

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting a console error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unhighlight is not a function'

Even after loading the Highlight.js plugin. Please find the attached HTML code.

```js
var userGuide = {
  id: null,
  initialize: function() {
    //debugger
    userGuide.initializeUSerGuide();
  },
  initializeUSerGuide: function() {
    var data1 = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam facilisis lectus et libero faucibus, convallis aliquam ante pharetra. Sed efficitur convallis lectus, in egestas tellus ornare tristique. Quisque blandit dolor non convallis convallis. Etiam facilisis velit ac dolor porta gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut suscipit efficitur diam, non rutrum mi posuere venenatis. Sed ullamcorper, ligula vitae convallis lacinia, lectus nibh scelerisque lacus, sed molestie lorem massa non orci. Duis sit amet justo magna. Nam malesuada neque et lectus scelerisque, sit amet rhoncus arcu blandit. Ut congue et est elementum bibendum. Morbi ligula mi, iaculis vitae pharetra ut, tristique eu arcu. Sed at dolor et magna pellentesque ornare. In urna sem, semper in augue id, tempus hendrerit augue. Maecenas vel porta justo. Aliquam porttitor elit eu neque hendrerit maximus.</p><p>Pellentesque mollis est vitae ornare elementum. Praesent sed neque ut lorem vestibulum malesuada eget a sem. Maecenas quam dui, ornare vitae orci nec, commodo vehicula nulla. Donec fermentum nisi eu mollis porttitor. Curabitur semper tortor eu magna cursus molestie. Praesent at pellentesque sapien, eget mollis quam. In vitae fringilla nisi, a ullamcorper sapien. Nunc ac enim porta, molestie leo quis, tristique sapien. Suspendisse in elit id urna faucibus rutrum.</p><p>Praesent convallis laoreet'
    $("#ListView").html(data1);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.finder {
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 5px;
  transition: top 0.15s ease-out;
}

.finder.active {
  top: 0;
}

.finder-input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  outline: none !important;
}

.finder-input.not-found {
  color: #e7353f;
}

.btn-finder {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.finder-input,
.btn-finder:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.finder-count {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #888;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-finder,
.finder-count {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.highlight {
  background: #ff8;
}

.highlight.active {
  background: #ffd71b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-5.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/blob/master/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /**
   * jQuery Finder Plugin
   * @author Danny McGee
   * @version 1.0
   * github.com/dannymcgee
   * 
   * Copyright 2018 Danny McGee
   * Released under the MIT License
   * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
   */

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(finder.activator).click(function() {
      finder.activate();
    });

    $(document).mousedown(function(event) {
      if (event.which === 1) {
        switch ($(event.target).attr('id') || $(event.target).parents().attr('id')) {
          case 'finderClose':
            finder.closeFinder();
            break;

          case 'finderPrev':
            finder.prevResult();
            break;

          case 'finderNext':
            finder.nextResult();
            break;

          default:
            return true;
        }
      }
    });

  });

  const finder = {
    activator: '[data-finder-activator]',

    content: '[data-finder-content]',

    wrapper: '[data-finder-wrapper]',

    scrollOffset: () => $(finder.wrapper).data('finderScrollOffset'),

    activate: () => {
      if (!$('#finder').length) {
        finder.createFinder();
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#finder').addClass('active');
        $('#finderInput').focus();
        if ($('#finderInput').val()) {
          finder.findTerm($('#finderInput').val());
        }
        $('#finderInput').on('input', function() {
          finder.findTerm($(this).val());
        });
      }, 50);
    },

    createFinder: () => {
      const finderElem = $('<div />')
        .attr({
          'id': 'finder',
          'class': 'finder'
        })
        .prependTo(finder.wrapper);

      const input = $('<input />')
        .attr({
          'id': 'finderInput',
          'type': 'text',
          'class': 'finder-input',
        })
        .appendTo(finderElem);

      const prev = $('<button />')
        .attr({
          'id': 'finderPrev',
          'class': 'btn btn-finder btn-finder-prev',
        })
        .appendTo(finderElem);

      const prevIcon = $('<i />')
        .attr({
          'class': 'fas fa-angle-up',
        })
        .appendTo(prev);

      const next = $('<button />')
        .attr({
          'id': 'finderNext',
          'class': 'btn btn-finder btn-finder-next',
        })
        .appendTo(finderElem);

      const nextIcon = $('<i />')
        .attr({
          'class': 'fas fa-angle-down',
        })
        .appendTo(next);

      const close = $('<button />')
        .attr({
          'id': 'finderClose',
          'class': 'btn btn-finder btn-finder-close',
        })
        .appendTo(finderElem);

      const closeIcon = $('<i />')
        .attr({
          'class': 'fas fa-times',
        })
        .appendTo(close);
    },

    closeFinder: () => {
      $('#finder').removeClass('active');
      $(finder.content).unhighlight();
    },

    resultsCount: 0,

    currentResult: 0,

    findTerm: (term) => {
      // highlight results
      $(finder.content).unhighlight();
      $(finder.content).highlight(term);

      // count results
      finder.resultsCount = $('.highlight').length;

      if (finder.resultsCount) {
        // there are results, scroll to first one
        finder.currentResult = 1;
        finder.scrollToCurrent();
      } else {
        // no results
        finder.currentResult = 0;
      }

      // term not found
      if (!finder.resultsCount && term) {
        $('#finderInput').addClass('not-found');
      } else {
        $('#finderInput').removeClass('not-found');
      }

      finder.updateCurrent();
    },

    scrollToCurrent: () => {
      let scrollingElement;

      let i = finder.currentResult - 1;
      $('.highlight').removeClass('active');
      $(`.highlight:eq(${i})`).addClass('active');

      let offsetTop = -100;
      if (finder.scrollOffset() !== null) {
        offsetTop = finder.scrollOffset() * -1;
      }

      $(finder.wrapper).scrollTo('.highlight.active', {
        offset: {
          left: 0,
          top: offsetTop,
        },
      });
    },

    prevResult: () => {
      if (finder.resultsCount) {
        if (finder.currentResult > 1) {
          finder.currentResult--;
        } else {
          finder.currentResult = finder.resultsCount;
        }
        finder.scrollToCurrent();
      }

      finder.updateCurrent();
    },

    nextResult: () => {
      if (finder.resultsCount) {
        if (finder.currentResult < finder.resultsCount) {
          finder.currentResult++;
        } else {
          finder.currentResult = 1;
        }
        finder.scrollToCurrent();
      }

      finder.updateCurrent();
    },

    updateCurrent: () => {
      if ($('#finderInput').val()) {
        if (!$('#finderCount').length) {
          const countElem = $('<span />')
            .attr({
              'id': 'finderCount',
              'class': 'finder-count',
            })
            .insertAfter('#finderInput');
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#finderCount').text(finder.currentResult + ' / ' + finder.resultsCount);
        }, 50);
      } else {
        $('#finderCount').remove();
      }
    },
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    userGuide.initialize();
  });
</script>
<div class="container-fluid page-content">
  <div class="app" data-finder-wrapper data-finder-scroll-offset="175">
    <button class="finder-activator" data-finder-activator>
            Search
        </button>
    <div class="content" data-finder-content id="ListView">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is a problem with your jquery. If you replace your line with <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> you will see  the error will not be there anymore.

Comment: Please consider removing all of the extra code in your question, to get it down to a [mre]. There are not a lot of people willing to wade through that many lines of code to search for where you're using `unhighlight` and debug it for you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

the blog entry https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22 is a it unclear, but what fixed it for me is to add both
the highlighter "core" functions

```
<script src="http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.js"></script>
```

as well as the "plugin" part:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.0/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js"></script>
```

and also you need to provide some css for the `.highlight` class